# Call specific stock location into inherited model - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I've defined on a custom module a new `stock.location` like this:

```
<record id="location_stock" model="stock.location">
    <field name="name">ReparacionUnidades</field>
    <field name="location_id" ref="stock.stock_location_locations_virtual"/>
    <field name="usage">production</field>
    <field name="company_id"></field>
</record>
```

Now, I want to set this location as default on two fields, with the new API, like this:

```
x_location_src_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string=u'Ubicacion Origen de Productos', required=True,
                                   readonly=False, default='ReparacionUnidades',
                                   help="Location where the system will look for components.")
x_location_dest_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string=u'Ubicacion Destino de Productos', required=True,
                                    readonly=False, default='ReparacionUnidades',
                                     help="Location where the system will look for components.")
```

With the `default` attribute, now, in this moment, this appears empty on the form.

Obviously, I'm not calling the location in the correct way, so, how can I call, or better, what will be the equivalent, of:

```
ref="stock.stock_location_locations_virtual"
```

On this case?

I've searched into the `stock_location` DB table, but really I have no clue.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've also tried like this:

```
def _static_location(self):
    return ReparacionUnidades
```

Then, call on `default` attribute, this `_static_location` object, but `ReparacionUnidades` is obviously not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
default=_static_location
```

and define your method like:

```
def _static_location(self):
     return self.env.ref('your_module_name.location_stock')
```

The method will have to be declared before the field.

Comment: LoL, dude, how I didn't notice that, Thank You so much.